# Character Table of the Monster

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, characters

Does anyone have a link to a website having the character table of the Griess Monster in characteristic $0$?

Comment: You can browse it in GAP using `Browse(CharacterTable("M"));`

Comment: The printed version in the ATLAS is 8 (very large) pages long, not including the explanatory text.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should extrapolate a tiny bit, I need to do calculations with it involving the entries for elements of order 2, hence only need the character degrees and the values for 2A and 2B, but don't really want to enter these manually from the Atlas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) to export the values from the character table library into a CSV file (openable with notepad or excel).

```
gap> ct:= CharacterTable("M");;
gap> classes := List( [ "1a", "2a", "2b" ],
> name -> Position( ClassNames( ct ), name ) );;
gap> PrintTo( "mon.csv", "1A,2A,2B\n", JoinStringsWithSeparator( List( Irr(ct),
> chi -> JoinStringsWithSeparator( chi{classes}, "," ) ), "\n" ) );
```

[Here is the result](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2014-02-12-Monster.csv).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that.

Comment: What is sum of degrees irreducible characters of the Monster? A Monster-number?:-)

Comment: The sum of the dimensions of the irreducible representations of the Monster is 5844076785304502808013602136.

Comment: How could I get a .txt file with the whole character table? I wanted to export it so I can work with it as a list in Mathematica, but I'm having a hard time figuring out this GAP system.